# Listing array number before value when printing as a list

Tags: java, netbeans

Hey I have this code currently

```
public void listNotes()
{
    for(String note : m_notes) {

        System.out.println(note);

    }
}
```

When I run the function within my program I would like it to print out every item of the list in this format:

> 0:Walk the dog
>   1:Go to the shop
>   2:sell Shoes

However right now it prints just the value stored in the variable.

If required I can post more of the program.

`m_notes` is a `Vector<string>`

```
private Vector<String> m_notes;

public Notebook()
{
    m_notes = new Vector<String>();
}
```

Comment: The definition/origin of m_notes would be nice to know..

Comment: Could it be that you ment "However right now it prints just the value stored in the *String*."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is a simple counter either with a for or with foreach:

**Foreach solution (generic):**

```
public void listNotes(){
    int i = 0;
    for(String note : m_notes) { 
        System.out.println(""+i+":"+note);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**For solution (Vector-specific):**

```
public void listNotes(){
    for(int i =0; i< m_notes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(""+i+":"+m_notes.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
List<String> list = //get the list
for(int i = 0 ; i< list.size() ; i++){
    System.out.println(i + ":" + list.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  public void listNotes(String[] m_notes)
  {
    int index = 0;
    for(String note : m_notes) {

        System.out.println(index + ":" + note);

        index++;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void listNotes() {
   Integer i = 0;
   for(String note : m_notes) {
       System.out.println(note);
       i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not really add anything to what the other answers are describing, it seems. I'm also curious as to why you use `Integer`, when `int` would be sufficient, and a better choice ?